# What determines cache speed?

Tags: file, caching, disk

I have a program that reads from a file and performs operations on it (count frequencies of words)....I  have 4 different file sizes, i get cache speed on all but the largest.  Why does the largest file only run at disk speed no matter how many times i run it?  Does too much ram usage restrict the cache from running? The large file is 27 gb.  Running on windows.  This is file caching, not CPU caching

Comment: How big are those files? How do you know you're running at "disk speed" or "cache speed"? How do you read the file?

Comment: It's going to depend on what OS you're using?

Comment: 27 gb, running on windows.  I have a counter that measure the speed the file is being read in.  Obviously cache speed is A LOT faster than disk speed.

Comment: This isn't really a correct use of the phrase cache.  Most people, when you ask a question like this, are going to think that you mean CPU cache, which has a size measured in KB to the lower end of MB.  What you're actually referring to is fitting the file in memory.  You're likely getting a lot of page faults in memory because the file cannot be totally stored in memory.  If you're talking about something other than CPU cache, please specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cache == memory. Run out of memory, you run out of cache. If you have a file that is greater than the size of the cache, and you're streaming through it, it's as if you had pretty much no cache at all. Cache only helps when you read the data again, it has no effect on the first time.

When the file is greater than the memory, then there is never any of the original file left in memory when you try to re-use it, thus the cache has pretty much no value in that case. The other dark side is that when you do that, you may well lose the cache on all of the other small files that the system accesses often and are no longer cached. So it may take a bit longer for things to reload and get back up to speed.